# Can I create a volume on my windows hyperv docker installation

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v

I need some straight answers about this as the current docker info and general Web info mixes hyperv and vmware info up.

I have installed docker on my windows 10 pro machine. I do not have vmware/virtual box installed I don't need it I have hyperv? I can use docker on a Linux Ubuntu box fairly well and I (think!) I understand volumes. Sorry for the background...

I am developing a node app and I simply want to have a volume within my Linux container mapped to a local directory on my windows machine, this should be simple but everytime I run my (lets say alpine linux) container '-v /c/Users:/somedata' the directory within the Linux /somedata directory is empty?

I just don't get this functionality on Windows? If you have a decent link I would be very grateful as I have been going over the docker info for two days and I feel I am nowhere!

If volumes are not supported between Windows and Linux because of the OS differences would the answer be to use copy within a Docker file? And simply copy my dev files into the container being created?

MANY MANY THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0):

I **have** been able to get a link to take place, but I don't really know what the rules are, yet.

(I am using Docker for windows 1.12.0-beta21 (build: 5971) )

You have to share the drive(s) in your docker settings (this may require logging in)

The one or two times I've gotten it to work, I used

`-v //d/vms/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`

(where I have a folder `D:\vms\mysql`)

(note the "//d" to indicate the drive letter)

I am trying to reproduce this with a different setup, though, and I am not having any luck.  Hopefully the next release will make this even easier for us!